# The General form of the Friedmann equation written in another way

Tags: cosmology, space-expansion, universe, curvature, cosmological-constant

Using the general form of the Friedmann equation:

$$H^2 =H_0^2(Ω_{m0}(1+z)^3+Ω_{r0}(1+z)^4+Ω_{k0}(1+z)^2+Ω_Λ)$$

and taking $a_0=1$, How can I derive that the Friedmann can be writing in the following way:
$$1= Ω_m(a) + Ω_r(a)+ Ω_k(a)+ Ω_Λ(a)~ ?$$
I am not sure how the left hand side equates 1.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.